# InternetSetOption change connection limit

Tags: c++, winapi, internetsetoption

How can I change the connection limit programmatically by calling the InternetSetOption function on a null handle ? i.e.,

How to use

```
INTERNET_OPTION_MAX_CONNS_PER_SERVER 
or
INTERNET_OPTION_MAX_CONNS_PER_SERVER
```

with

```
InternetSetOption()
```